How can I define reusable class methods for common where clauses to SQLModel models preserving aliasing functionality?
I have a project using the SQLModel library where models define class methods returning commonly used where clauses.
For example:
class Person(SQLModel, table=True):
    age: int
    
    @classmethod
    def where_of_age(cls):
        return cls.age >= 18

Can be used as:
with session:
    query = Person.select().where(Person.where_of_age())
    result = session.exec(query)

This is useful to avoid repetition of frequent where clauses in queries on a certain table, but is even more useful when the where clause is relevant on many tables and can be extracted in a parent class. For example:
class SoftDeletable(SQLModel):
    deletedAt: DateTimeType | None = None
    
    @classmethod
    def deleted(cls):
        return cls.deletedAt.is_not(None)

class Person(SQLModel, SoftDeletable, table=True):
    ...

However, this breaks when combined with the aliased() function sometimes necessary when performing subqueries:
aliasedPerson = aliased(Person, some_sub_query)
query = Person.select_from(Person).join(some_sub_query).where(aliasedPerson.deleted())

Here aliased should point to the usage of Person within the results of some_sub_query, but actually points to the Person table directly.
The reason seems to be that aliasedPerson is not a subclass of Person, but rather a proxy object that relays method
calls to the Person class (which knows nothing of the aliasing)
I could of course solve this issue by having the deleted() method be a function that receives the proxy object as parameter instead:
class SoftDeletable(SQLModel):
    deletedAt: DateTimeType | None = None
    
def deleted(target):
    return target.deletedAt.is_not(None)
    
aliasedPerson = aliased(Person, some_sub_query)
query = Person.select_from(Person).join(some_sub_query).where(deleted(aliasedPerson))

but that seems less than ideal:

when composing multiple where clauses this way the parameter must be passed around despite being implicit
extension/overriding becomes difficult

Is there any simple way to preserve the benefits of defining them as methods while supporting the use of aliased()?
